# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, PATH is corrent

Tags: java, path, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to create a simple program, but of course JAVA thinks otherwise: it's not that simple.
I need to dynamically instantiate a class, meaning that the user gives a class name from keyboard, and then an object of the class type with that name is created. 
Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class NimMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader Olvaso = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String be = Olvaso.readLine();
        String[] kapcsolo = be.split(" ");

        switch (kapcsolo[0]) {      
            case "uj": uj(kapcsolo);    
            case "lep":         
            case "listaz":
            case "ment":
            case "tolt":
        }}


    public static void uj(String[] s) {
        try {
            int b = 2;
            String nev = s[1]; 
            Class NimJatek = Class.forName(nev);
            Constructor con = NimJatek.getConstructor(String[].class, int.class);
            Object xyz = con.newInstance(s,b);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The class which fails to instantiate is `NimJatek`, which is in the same directory, in the same (unnamed) package. 
When I try to run this program, it gives the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you baffle yourself by your not very clear constructs. At the end you use the second value of your input string to be loaded as class. If you provide the correct string there it will be laoded correctly. The input string:

```
"uj NimJatek"
```

will lead to a correctly found class NimJatek - provided NimJatek is in your root package AND this root package is on your classpath.

Comment: I'm new to Java, and to programming. The input stream you gave was correct, but then it's not doing what I want it to. The input string would be "uj WHATEVERNAME" and the WHATEVERNAME would be an instantiation of the class NimJatek, How can I achieve this?

Comment: As a beginner of java I recommend you to learn first the basics, before you work with introspection. What is a class? What is an instance? What is inheritence? What is a type? What is a variable? What is a constant? What is constructor? What is a package? What is a classpath? And - most important - how do this all work together?

Comment: I did that with c++, JAVA is mandatory at the university, where I study. So far it has been a piece of ****. I think I understand why people hate JAVA.

Comment: C and C++ do not know the concept of classpath. Both try to find files relative to the current directory. Latter is not always under your control. In java you define the classpath to be used either in the jar file or in the command line which starts the JVM. A Class.forName always loads a class from the classpath and not from the filesystem path. And that's why I love java. Everything is much clearer and standardized than in C, if you once got the concept.

Comment: I know, I understand it, at least now. Honestly, it's not just these technical differences, but the whole language feel off to me. I feel like that JAVA forces me to think in objects and ONLY objects. Now, this might be a good thing, I can't tell yet, but I do now, that I feel like a kind of restriction, like being in a box. I like to think freely, and in my experience so far JAVA does not really allow this. Also we can only use NOTEPAD++ and DOS command prompt, which is a bit daunting